# Sort Property File By Length of Value

Tags: bash, shell, properties

Looking to see if anyone has some shell or bash magic that would allow for sorting of a property file by the character length of the value of the properties.

**For example:**

Input as `input.properties` file:

```
short-but-long-value=12345
this-is-a-really-long-property-name-with-short-value-length=12
foo=1234
bar2=123
var1=AUTHENTICATE, DISCOVER_SCHEMA, ENABLE, PROVISIONING
var2=OU=OU_SOMETHING,OU=OU_SOMTHING_ELSE,OU=OU_MORE_SOMETHING,OU=LAST_SOMETHING
```

Sorted output as `output.properties` file:

```
this-is-a-really-long-property-name-with-short-value-length=12
bar2=123
foo=1234
short-but-long-value=12345
var1=AUTHENTICATE, DISCOVER_SCHEMA, ENABLE, PROVISIONING
var2=OU=OU_SOMETHING,OU=OU_SOMTHING_ELSE,OU=OU_MORE_SOMETHING,OU=LAST_SOMETHING
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Inian `output.properties` is the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `awk`/`sort` and `cut` logic:-

```
awk -F"=" '{ st = index($0,"="); print length(substr($0,st+1)),$0 }' input.properties | sort -n | cut -d" " -f2-
this-is-a-really-long-property-name-with-short-value-length=12
bar2=123
foo=1234
short-but-long-value=12345
var1=AUTHENTICATE, DISCOVER_SCHEMA, ENABLE, PROVISIONING
var2=OU=OU_SOMETHING,OU=OU_SOMTHING_ELSE,OU=OU_MORE_SOMETHING,OU=LAST_SOMETHING
```

Write it a file as

```
awk -F"=" '{ st = index($0,"="); print length(substr($0,st+1)),$0 }' input.properties | sort -n | cut -d" " -f2- > output.properties
```

Comment: @chepner, I think Inian's update fixed the length issue. I added a couple properties with strings and the latest works as desired. A note for others if you want descending sort, you can do `sort -rn` instead of `sort -n`.

Comment: Yeah, just forgot to delete the comment.

Comment: @Inian, This worked for the sample property values, however when I ran it against a larger properties file with spaces and equals as part of the values it seems to have issues.

Comment: Can you share the updated input for which it failed and I can provide an updated answer

Comment: @VenomFangs: Refer my update, and don't forget to _accept_ now.

Comment: @VenomFangs: It is working fine for me, Can you double-check once and run the command exactly as it is?

Comment: @Inian, much appreciated. I missed the 2nd dash in -f2- in my testing but found it shortly after. Things look good now.